Error: Failed to create deployment: the server could not find the requested resource (post deployments.apps) - Terraform and Kubernetes
This is my first question, so it may have some unclearity. I will try my best to provide all information.
I am new to TerraForm. I want to monitor my resources using Grafana and Prometheus. For this I am using Kubernetes (k3s) locally on my system. I have created kubernetes manifests and when I am use manual deployments, using kubectl apply -f xyz.yml, the resources are up and running fine.
Now I want to use IAC and for that I am using TerraForm. I want to achieve the same results by using TerraForm, but I have encountered several errors while doing so.
Here are the errors I am getting when I am using terraform apply -auto-approve command, after init and plan:

Error: Failed to create deployment: the server could not find the requested resource (post deployments.apps)
with kubernetes_deployment.grafana,
on grafana.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_deployment" "grafana":
1: resource "kubernetes_deployment" "grafana" {`
Error: Failed to create deployment: the server could not find the requested resource (post deployments.apps)
with kubernetes_deployment.prometheus,
on prometheus.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_deployment" "prometheus":
1: resource "kubernetes_deployment" "prometheus" {`

Here is my provider.tf:
    terraform {
      required_version = ">= 0.13"

      required_providers {
    
        kubernetes = {
         source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
         version = ">= 2.0.0"
        } 
    }

And I am defining resources in .tf as
    resource "kubernetes_deployment" "grafana" {
      metadata {
        name = "grafana"
        labels = {
          app = "grafana"
        }
      }

      spec {
        replicas = 1

        selector {
          match_labels = {
            app = "grafana"
          }
        }
       ... 


I have also tried same with kubectl provider by gavinbunney:
    terraform {
      required_version = ">= 0.13"
    
      required_providers {

         kubectl = {
           source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
           version = ">= 1.14.0"
         }
      }
    }

But had no luck. Same errors are being generated.
I am assuming that the issue is somewhere in provider.tf.

Which version of K3s are you running?

I am using k3s v1.28.7

Can you also try with kubernetes_deployment_v1 instead of kubernetes_deployment?

Same results with kubernetes_deployment_v1

And which configuration are you using when running without terraform? The ~/.kube/config file or something else? Do you have a provider "kubernetes" bock defined anywhere?

When I am using manual deployment, all I do is create namespaces, configmaps (for prometheus.yml, and blackbox.yml) and then apply all deployments and services yml files. After that I can access my pods using my kubectl node ip and nodePort of serivce I want to access. It might be the default ~/.kube/config but I don't know exactly.
And for provider "kubernetes", I  am using hashicorp kubernetes provider in my provider.tf.

That's not enough. You have to tell the provider where to look for configuration. Take a look here.

Thanks @MarkoE , indeed there was a misconfiguration with my provider.
